# Bottom Sheet doesn't close when navigating to different screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, bottom-sheet

I'm new to programming and when I navigate to the new screen and the bottom sheet doesn't close [here's the picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dP1o.jpg). I'm using `@gorhom/bottom-sheet^4`.I have done some research and I know that using `useFocusEffect` could acheive it but i dont really know how. Can someone help me on this?

```
<BottomSheetModal
    enablePanDownToClose={true}
    ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
    index={0}
    snapPoints={snapPoint}
    backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
  >
    <View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Settings");
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Settings</Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Saved");
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Saved</Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Delete");
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Delete</Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Log out</Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  </BottomSheetModal>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few ways to do it. Here are two:

1. Add [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) that runs when your screen with `BottomSheetModal` is unfocused:

```
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    return () => bottomSheetRef.current?.close()
  }, [])
);
```

2. Close `BottomSheetModal`, whenever you are leaving your screen. In order to do that, you have to call `bottomSheetModalRef.current?.close` while navigating:

   ```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate("Settings");
      bottomSheetModalRef.current?.close();
    }}
   >
    <Text style={styles.modalText}>Settings</Text>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate("Saved");
      bottomSheetModalRef.current?.close();
    }}
   >
    <Text style={styles.modalText}>Saved</Text>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate("Delete");
      bottomSheetModalRef.current?.close();
    }}
   >
    <Text style={styles.modalText}>Delete</Text>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React Navigation you can also automatically close any open modals whenever navigation changes like so:

```
import { useBottomSheetModal } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet'

const Navigation = () => {
    const { dismissAll: dismissAllModals } = useBottomSheetModal()

    return <NavigationContainer  
            onStateChange={() =>
                dismissAllModals()
            }>

           {...}

           </NavigationContainer>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actionSheetRef.current.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `backdropComponent` prop to the BottomSheet component. The backdrop component will receive animated props that indicate the position and index of the sheet

The Backdrop component appears after the bottom sheet modal has opened and animated, If you use this the `bottomsheet` will disappear if you click anywhere

**Here are some examples of using the backdropComponent prop:**

```
 import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetBackdrop } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
  const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    (props: any) => (
      <BottomSheetBackdrop
        enableTouchThrough={false}
        pressBehavior={"close"}
        appearsOnIndex={0}
        disappearsOnIndex={-1}
        {...props}
      />
    ),
    []
  );

  <BottomSheet backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}/>
```